# Chart.js ignora configuraciones

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tengo el siguiente código

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {

      type: 'horizontalBar',

      data: {
        labels:['uno','dos','tres','cuatro','cinco','seis','siete','ocho','nueve','diez'],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Resultado",
            backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
            data: [3, 6, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6, 2],
          },
          {
            label: "Perfil",
            backgroundColor: "lightpink",
            data: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 8, 2]
          }

        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            autoSkip: false,

            ticks: {
              suggestedMin: 0,
              suggestedMax: 11,
              autoSkip: false

            }
          }]
        }
      }

    });
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
```

Pero hay errores con lo que paso en options :

`suggestedMin: 0` : Esto sólo funciona si elimino `suggestedMax: 11,`

`suggestedMax: 11`: esto sólo funciona si elimino `suggestedMin: 0`

`autoSkip:false`: Esto sólo funciona cuando uno de los dos anteriores no está.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola Emiliano, la variable "maxChart" donde la declaras?
¿Que errores te muestra?

Comment: @Ricardo no me muestra ningún error, sólo no cumple esas tres opciones a la vez, la variable maxChart en ese caso es 11, ya lo modifiqué para que no halla confuciones

Answer (score 0):

Según mi experiencia es porque suggestedMin y suggestedMax van en ticks de yAxes. Ya que es ahí donde estás delimitando. Así lo utilizo yo.

```
    scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Producto'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 10,
                        autoSkip: false,
                        beginAtZero: false
                    }

                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Cantidad'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        suggestedMax: 10,
                        stepSize: 0,
                        scaleSteps: 10,
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 20,
                    }
                }]
            }
```